# Pandas MultiIndex select rows where value is between two levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a MultiIndex with 3 levels `name`, `lower` and `upper`.
I want to query data where `name` is some specific value and some number `n` `lower < n < upper` (does not have to be `<`, could also be `<=`)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'],
    'lower': [0, 3, 0, 6],
    'upper': [2, 5, 5, 11],
    'some_data': [0, 1, 2, 3],
})
df = df.set_index(['name', 'lower', 'upper'], drop=True)
df = df.sort_index()

print(df)
#                   some_data
# name lower upper           
# bar  0     5              2
#      6     11             3
# foo  0     2              0
#      3     5              1

# Let's say I want to get the data where name is 'foo' and 1 is between lower and upper
print(df.loc[('foo', slice(None, 1), slice(1, None)), :])
#                   some_data
# name lower upper           
# foo  0     2              0
```

But now I want to have:

- the data where `name` is 'foo' and 1 is between `lower` and `upper`
- the data where `name` is 'foo' and 4 is between `lower` and `upper`
- the data where `name` is 'bar' and 7 is between `lower` and `upper`

The result might look like this:

```
               some_data
name contains  
foo  1                 0
foo  4                 1
bar  7                 3
```

Doing this one by one is slow. Is there any way to select multiple rows?

Note: I don't have to use a DataFrame nor do I have to use a MultiIndex. If there is some data structure that is better suited for this job, I would be happy to use that.

Comment: An interval index suits best for this

Comment: kindly add more rows to your dataframe, and explain a bit more what you have in mind. Get rows where C is between A and B, or rows where 1 is between A and B?

Comment: Is an interval index able to work with overlapping intervals?

Comment: Ok, there is a bug preventing me from using an interval index within a MultiIndex https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25298

Comment: kindly add example data for the multiple values of `n`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.between` and pass columns `'A'` and `'B'` without having to make them levels until later. In the below example, there are two rows where `'C'` is between 'A' and 'B':

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [0, 3, 6, 9],
    'B': [2, 5, 8, 11],
    'C': [0, 1, 2, 10],
})

df_selected = df[df['C'].between(df['A'],df['B'])].set_index(['A', 'B'], drop=True)
```

Result:

```
       C
A B     
0 2    0
9 11  10
```

Answer (score 0):

An interval index works fine for your example case:

```py
intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df.index.get_level_values('lower'),
                                         df.index.get_level_values('upper'), 
                                         closed = 'both')
arr = intervals.get_indexer_for([1])

df.iloc[arr].loc['foo']
 
             some_data
lower upper           
0     2              0
```

kindly add more example data for multiple values of n, and if possible, make the multiIndex overlapping